# How to customize reports in openerp 7?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I modified the rml code for my desired changes such as removing/renaming a column, even after modifying the code in rml changes are not taking place in pdf report. Is there any compiled code of rml file?
I even modified sxw file still no change in output.

Then I used Apache OpenOffice to modify report but the changes I make are not being reflected!

Comment: Sometimes the report is saved the first time in the table `ir_attachment` table. Try to print the report with other different data to render a different report

Comment: If you modify .sxw file using openoffice than you must convert .sxw to .rml file. After than it will give you desire output. And make sure you are change the correct path files.

Comment: The command which u gave is not working

Comment: This is the command i used,                                                                      python openerp_sxw2rml.py /D:/OpenERP 7.0-20150813/server/openerp/addons/sale/report/sale_order.sxw> /D:/OpenERP 7.0-20150813/server/openerp/addons/sale/report/sale_order.rml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please you can try check with your process in the below mentioned way.

**In your case You must have to do the following way for the report to print with PDF format :**

1.You can check with report ids which is same as in the report menu (print opetation).

2.you can also renaming that ids and menu ids if you want to customize report in your module.

3.you can check your report with your customize report with same database

4.If you are fail in point 3 then you should try to create a new database and install your customize report module on it  and check to print that report on it.

I hope you may have to solve this issue and try my steps to do your job make a easily and quickly.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)